# Best way to search response data in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I have an in-house application that I'm building with React Native. I'm still very new to React Native and trying to figure out the most efficient way of doing this.

I have these piece of code that is taking data in from our LDAP servers and assigning it to hooks.

```
.then((response) => {
    setName(response.data.ldap_users[0].realname);
    setPosition(response.data.ldap_users[0].position);
    setPhone(response.data.ldap_users[0].phone);
    setEmail(response.data.ldap_users[0].email_address);
    setUsername(response.data.ldap_users[0].username);
    setRealName(response.data.ldap_users[0].real_name);
    setRoom(response.data.ldap_users[0].room);
    setIsSending(false);
    return data;
```

All of our users have user names that start with A, B, or C example A67345 or B45437 etc.

However, our elevated accounts have letters like D, and E and sometimes in the array they end up in the 0 slot. I need to avoid this.

So example, Billy has 2 accounts, his main account has a username of A5555 and he has an elevated account username of D6629.
In the response for the username his D6629 may be in slot 0 and his A account, which I need is in slot 1, making the code above useless.

I am not quite familiar enough with how React Native loops through and finds starts with and grab that variable out.

What is the best approach to this?

Any other language I would just use a for each loop looking for a startsWith("A")

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you need `if` check like this.

```
    if(response.data.ldap_users[0].username.charAt(0).toUpperCase() === 'A' || other conditions){
             // push your data here
    }
```

you could use `foreach` loop like

```
    response.data.ldap_users[0].foreach((user) => {
      if(user.username.charAt(0).toUpperCase() === 'A' ||charAt(0).toUpperCase() === 'B' ||charAt(0).toUpperCase() === 'C'){
    // add user user to the array here 
    }else{
    // ignore
    }

})
```

Comment: Ok I had a if check and it only works some times. Just make a bunch of If checks for each slot?